# My CRUD app works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, create-react-app, crud

I've created a CRUD app and it works locally, but I can't get it to work fine on heroku. It deploys correctly, the website seems to work, but then I can't get the items I need from the database, as it keeps saying connection refused. 
I added the .env variables to Heroku, as well as setting the port to `process.env.PORT || 5000` and `app.listen(port)`, I'm not sure what's causing the error. I also have a Procfile with web: `node server.js`, and a "start" script in package.json that points to server.js. It seems that the server doesn't start at all.
Here the repo in case you want to have a look https://github.com/ThomYorke7/inventory, here the app on heroku https://boardgamenerd.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Have you verified that you are in fact attempting to connect to the correct database server?

Comment: can you try connecting to remote db server from local?

Comment: When I run "node server.js" locally in VS Code I get two console.logs, one from `connection.once(open, () => console.log("Connected to database")` and the other from `app.listen(port, ()=> console.log("The server is running on: ${port}")`. This latter shows port 5000 in the console. So yes, I suppose I can connect from local.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions must be self-contained; we're not going to go off-site and dig through your code looking for problems. Please [edit] the relevant information directly into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that **your application has a backend (server) and a frontend (client) which are served differently locally than on Heroku.**

I suppose locally your client is running on `localhost:3000` (as it is the default with create-react-app you bootstrapped).
While your backend is running on `localhost:5000`, your client's package.json contains this line to make it work locally:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

If I visit this page of your app: *https://boardgamenerd.herokuapp.com/ > boardgames*,
then I face these errors on the browser console:

```
boardgames-list.jsx:18

Error: Network Error
    at e.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.p.onerror (xhr.js:83)
```

```
xhr.js:178

GET http://localhost:5000/boardgames/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

It tells you that your production version still calls backend on `localhost:5000`.

**I.) First I'd try to fix these fetches by changing to relative URLs.**

E.g. the above example ([boardgames-list.jsx:18](https://github.com/ThomYorke7/inventory/blob/master/client/src/components/boardgames-list.jsx))

❌ **your current script has hardcoded localhost fetch at the moment:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/boardgames/')
      .then((response) => {
        setBoardgames(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

✔️ **make it relative to root by removing "http://localhost:5000":**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('/boardgames/')
      .then((response) => {
        setBoardgames(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

And it will work on Heroku. In case it wouldn't: see my suggestion below.

**II.) Second, a suggestion:**
Now your https://boardgamenerd.herokuapp.com/boardgames route uses the following backend endpoint to fetch data: https://boardgamenerd.herokuapp.com/boardgames/

The difference is only the last slash (**"/"**) character which can be confusing and cause more issues later!
**It is a best practice to add a differentiator path element to your backend endpoints,** like `/api/`. For example: `https://boardgamenerd.herokuapp.com/api/boardgames` So you can be sure by first sight which `GET` request related to the backend and which one to the client.

If you'd go with this solution, you will need to add the following to your `server.js`:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')))
    // required to serve SPA on heroku production without routing problems; it will skip only 'api' calls
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      app.get(/^((?!(api)).)*$/, (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'))
      })
    }
```

`/^((?!(api)).)*$/` regex skips URLs containing "api" in their path, so they won't be served static as the client/build folder's content - api calls won't be served from static and will work fine.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I knew the issue was probably lying in the "hardcoded" fetch paths, but I didn't know how to make them relative. However, now I'm facing two new problems. The first, is that when I add the differentiator path, the pages where I download and show the items go blank. I suppose is because I have to edit the paths adding /api somewhere but I don't know where exactly (whether the single routes or server.js). The second point is that when I try to add/delete or edit an item of the database, the website behaves strangely, showing raw data from the database.

Comment: Yes, once **(I)** you need to do the endpoint changes in your **server.js**, e.g.: `app.use('/api/boardgames', boardgamesRouter);` and also **(II)** don't forget to fetch the data on these new endpoints in your **React components' fetch**, e.g.: `axios.get('/api/boardgames/')`. These are the two key points to use `/api/` in your backend endpoint path. It may needs finetuning on backend routing, you may need to refactor to some other express middleware to get it work (expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). *Edit:* I fixed the path in my example and typos.

Comment: @ThomYorke Have you been able to fix the paths?

Comment: Yes I did. I was struggling with the snippet you suggested as I pasted as it was a middleware, without editing my app.get('*') lines. Then I realize that the snippet was basically a conditional app.get and I pasted in the right spot. Now I think everything works as it should and I thank you immensely for your help.

Comment: Great to hear, I am glad it helped.